# How to carry cologne bottles in hand luggage and prevent losses?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, tips-and-tricks, hand-luggage

Say I have a cologne bottle of 100 ml that I want to carry in my hand luggage on a plane trip.

100 ml is the limit so it should be fine for the transport regulations (if not, please let me know!).

The problem I always encounter is regarding the storage of the bottle: how to prevent it from leaking?

What I normally do is to put it in a plastic bag, so that the possible loss remains there. It is fine, only that the bottle ends up quite wet.

What would be a better approach?

Comment: Related regarding liquid container size: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39791/22140

Comment: Cover the cap, after the bottle has been closed, with a plastic bag tightly with some rubber bands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This trick is used by many 
Piece of Plastic on bottle before you close the cap

That will prevent spills. After that put it in ziploc type plastic bag 
Check at home before you put it in luggage.

[image: Plastic bottle cap]

Comment: This looks promising! I will check it and come back with the results of the experience :)

Comment: It worked very well :) the only little problem was that some cologne popped out during the removal of the plastic.

Comment: Nice to know. I will try to find solution to spillage during plastic removal. I am going to experiment keeping bottle upright for a while before opening the cap so that there is not much left in the plastic, liquid may drip back in the bottle. Be sure to wait for a while after removing bottles from the baggage to minimize spill.  Thanks for voting!

Comment: An ingenious tip - and I love the cloud imagery!